# Ubuntu Core Pi Installation: x509 certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core

I am flashing Ubuntu core on a Raspberry PI 3. I followed the steps described in the website https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3. When the configuration reaches the profile setup step, it asks for an email address. I entered the email address and I got the following error.

```
error: while creating user: cannot create user "<email address>": get https://login.ubuntu.com/api/v2/keys/<email adddress>: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

I have created an account and added the SSH keys to the Ubuntu one website.

Comment: I am having the same issue, tried creating a new account, but still no luck. Any of you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this message today and was hoping to find an answer here :-(

I think what happened for me is that my Ubuntu id was very old (2010) and I hadn't used it since maybe 2014.

I had to delete my Ubuntu account and recreate it on their site (https://login.ubuntu.com). Sadly this meant I lost my original username (when I tried to re-use it it said it was already in use).